# Count Unique Date Only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel doc with two tables. The first table as a list of unique providers and the number of visits for each provider. The second table has the provider, the date of service, and a description of what it was.

Table 1:

```
Provider    No of Visits
Hospital1   3
```

Table 2:

```
Provider    Date of Service    Description
Hospital1   3/6/18             Emergency
Hospital1   3/6/18             Radiology
Hospital1   6/15/18            Clinic
```

The formula used to calculate the value in table 1 is

```
=IF([@[Provider]]="","", (COUNTIF(Table2[Provider], A8)))
```

How do I get it so that it counts only unique DOS? Table 1 should have No of Visits listed as 2 instead of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it as,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table2[Provider]=[@Provider])/(COUNTIFS(Table2[Date of], Table2[Date of], Table2[Provider], [@Provider])+(Table2[Provider]<>[@Provider])))
```

[image]